# How to make Firefox restart after add-on is installed?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a new tab page replacement add-on for Firefox. After the add-on is installed, Firefox browser does not restart. As a result, the add-on is not functional. User would have to manually restart Firefox and then the add-on would be functional.

My question is: how to make Firefox restart when add-on is installed? Many Firefox add-ons I have tried do this. What do I need to implement to make Firefox restart after an add-on is installed?

BTW, this is an add-on developed with SDK, not a boot-strapped add-on.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to restart? It's a feature that addon-sdk addons don't need a restart. I'd say you may did something wrong if it doesn't work without restarting.

Comment: SDK addons do not restart. So you must have a bug if its not working. SDK addons never need restart.

Comment: @kapep Take 3 similar add-ons as example, New Tab King, New Tab Plus, and IOS7 New Tab. After any of these add-ons are installed, a notification message box displays and informs user that:

New Tab King will be installed after you restart Firefox.
New Tab Plus will be installed after you restart Firefox.
IOS7 New Tab will be installed after you restart Firefox.

User then clicks on the "Restart Now" button in the notification message box to restart Firefox.

Right now, after my add-on is installed, there is no such notification message box. What I want is to have it show up.

Comment: Just for your knowledge though this is how you restart see this gist here: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/99c3e014fb034c834ebb

Comment: @Noitidart I see what you are saying. I guess the examples I mentioned must be bootstrapped add-ons. How do I go about finding what's keeping my add-on from working properly? The add-on should function without restart, but right now it needs a restart then it works fine. Where might the problem lie?

Comment: @startupfounder Yes, but all of those addons lack the "No Restart" badge ([like you see here for example](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/)) - this means they must restart because they are not developed with the addon-sdk. For more modern addon-sdk addons, restarting is usually not necessary.

Comment: You don't have to restart at all, homepage new tab addon doesnt need restart. Upload your code to github and share link ill check it out for you. To figure out if you have bugs use the Browser Console (`ctrl` + `shift` + `j`)

Answer (score 1):

You've not explained why a restart is required, I assume that it is not, but you cannot require a restart without building the add-on as an old-school xul add-on, using `install.rdf` and `chrome.manifest` files.